# How to set up a ckan instance using docker image?

Tags: docker, ubuntu-16.04, ckan

Hey I want to set up a ckan instance (the latest version) on ubuntu 16.04 xenial in a docker image. Is there any proper documentation or step wise process for doing this? Or can someone guide me on how to do this? I am new to docker.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no straight forward documentation for setting up in docker. Here is what I did.

1. clone the ckan version you want.
2. go to that folder modify the Dockerfile
3. Run d`docker build -t .`

and you are done. Ofcourse you need postgres, solr and redis which you can find proper Docker files in `contrib/docker`